# How do i associate my model in rails between teams, users and organizations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am doing a project in rails which allows multiple users to be a part of organization(user belongs to only one organization). Organization has multiple teams and user also can belong to multiple teams. Besides, the organization part I did other associations like this.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end 

class Team < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

My thought on adding organizations association is like this.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :teams
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

Are there any other ways, so that I can add organization model which would be helpful for future purposes too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend foregoing the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship in favor of `has_many through:`, which will allow you to have more flexibility with the `Organization` model.

Something like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :organizations
  has_many :teams, through: :organizations
end
```

---

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :organizations
  has_many :users, through: :organizations
end
```

---

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :teams
end
```

---

This way your associations are defined cleanly between three models without the Rails magic of `has_and_belongs_to_many`. This allows you use of the `Organization` model.